# Отдельная Activity, отдельный Service. Получить указатель на Service

Tags: android

Есть два отдельных проекта. В одном служба, в другом само приложение. Задача - обмен данными между ними. Если делать всё в одном проекте то вопросов нет. Но как мне в приложении получить указатель на свою же службу? Все примеры идут как локальный биндинг, а нужен раздельный. На примере http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/, но это локальный биндинг.
Вот строки оттуда

```
BoundService mBoundService;

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BoundService.class);
```

Интент заменю на свой

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my_action");
```

Но как мне получить и создать сам объект службы, которая находиться в другом проекте? Что бы взаимодействовать с ней и её методами?

```
timestampText.setText(mBoundService.getTimestamp());
```

Или может есть пример с обменом в раздельном биндинге? Как и через что? В любом случае надо как-то получить объект службы.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13748108/3212712):

```
Intent intentForService = new Intent(context);
String packageName = "com.example.package";
String className = "ServiceClassName";
intentForService.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName,
    packageName+"."+className));
```

Comment: Прошу прошения, но как и где это использовать?  Добавить в приложении заменив пакет на имя пакеты слуюбы и имя службы? Я правильно понял?

Comment: @Kamenev_D, ну, по идее, этот интент надо использовать в активити, в методе bindService...

Comment: @Kamenev_D, да, замените packageName  на пакет приложения-сервиса и className - это имя класса-сервиса из другого приложения. Т.е. ComponentName принимает два аргумента - пакет и полное имя класса

Comment: className не определяются.Где они объявлены, что подключить надо?

Comment: @Kamenev_D, я исправил ответ. Там опечатка была. Это просто строковая переменная, содержащая имя класса. Работать всё это будет только если этот класс лежит в основном пакете приложения-сервиса.

Comment: Извиняюсь но не пойму. Объявил. Но как мне добраться до MyService? Т.е надо добавить файлы сервиса к проекту активити? Или наоборот?

Comment: Ничего добавлять, вроде, не надо. Надо лишь знать полное имя класса из другого приложения. Возможно, надо ешё в приложении-сервисе в манифесте ему `exported="true"` прописать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40824/discussion-between-kamenev-d-and-).

Comment: Насколько я понял, данный код подключается к службе, которая не своя. В моем случае прибиндиться я могу без проблем т.к служба моя. ВОпрос в том, как передавать туда сюда данные?

Comment: @Kamenev_D, но у вас же вопрос о другом... "Но как мне получить и создать сам объект службы, которая находиться в другом проекте? Что бы взаимодействовать с ней и её методами?"

Comment: Проект то мой.Подключиться это одно, а как выйти на службу?